# Using WIndows PowerShell 1.0 or 2.0 to evaluate performance of executable files

Tags: performance, powershell, time

I am writing a simple script on Windows PowerShell in order to evaluate performance of executable files.

The important hypothesisi is the following: I have an executable file, it can be an application written in any possible language (.net and not, Viual-Prolog, C++, C, everything that can be compiled as an `.exe` file). I want to profile it getting execution times.

I did this:

```
Function Time-It {
    Param ([string]$ProgramPath, [string]$Arguments)
    $Watch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
    $NsecPerTick = (1000 * 1000 * 1000) / [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::Frequency
    Write-Output "Stopwatch created! NSecPerTick = $NsecPerTick"
    $Watch.Start() # Starts the timer
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($ProgramPath, $Arguments)
    $Watch.Stop() # Stops the timer
    # Collectiong timings
    $Ticks = $Watch.ElapsedTicks
    $NSecs = $Watch.ElapsedTicks * $NsecPerTick
    Write-Output "Program executed: time is: $Nsecs ns ($Ticks ticks)"
}
```

This function uses stopwatch.
Well, the functoin accepts a program path, the stopwatch is started, the program run and the stopwatch then stopped. Problem: the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` is asynchronous and the next instruction (watch stopped) is not executed when the application finishes. A new process is created...

I need to stop the timer once the program ends.

I thought about the `Process` class, thicking it held some info regarding the execution times... not lucky...

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Process.WaitForExit()`

```
$proc = new-object "System.Diagnostics.Process"
$proc.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
$proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$proc.Start()
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: But it is not static... I should create a Process object but don't really understand how to set the executable path...

Comment: `$proc = new-object "System.Diagnostics.Process"` and then just set the properties. You can follow the .NET documentation, the classes work the same, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [kprobst's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200359/using-windows-powershell-1-0-or-2-0-to-evaluate-performance-of-executable-files/5200374#5200374), combined with the [Measure-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee176899.aspx) CmdLet, for a complete solution:

```
$proc = new-object "System.Diagnostics.Process"
$proc.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
$proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$timeSpan = (MeasureCommand { 
                                $proc.Start()
                                $proc.WaitForExit()
                            }
            );
"Program executed: Time is {0} seconds" -f $timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
```